# Not Installing Sqlite 3 on CentOS correctly

Tags: php, sqlite, centos

I need to get sqlite 3 installed for php on a CentOS but its still telling that it's not installed.

I did the command and got this message:

```
yum install sqlite
Package sqlite-3.6.20-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I looked into php.ini and notice this, but not sure if it's any use

```
[sqlite]
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.configuration.php#ini.sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
;sqlite3.extension_dir =:
```

Let me know what else you need?

Comment: Did you build this PHP install?  Do you see an .so file for it in your ext dir?  `On Linux or Unix operating systems, if you build PDO as a shared extension, you must build SQLite as a shared extension using the --with-sqlite=shared configure option.`

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Did you look at your phpinfo() output? Have you taken a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php?

Comment: no .so file for sqlite, and I have php 5.3.3

Comment: You'll need to use phpize and build it form source then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite support for PHP is included in the `php-pdo` package.

```
yum install php-pdo
```